# Handsontable: getting string range from coordinates

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Is there a proper way to get range string (e.g. `B5:B13`) from coordinates (e.g. `[4,1,4,12]`) in `handsontable`?

I've tried to find one within official documentation, looked for an answer through 13 pages of `handsontable`-tagged questions here, but found nothing. I thought it should be a rather popular issue, but it seems not:)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should add some code. what do you mean by coordinates?

Comment: @user3273700 There is a callback method [`afterSelectionEnd`](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.28.0/Hooks.html#event:afterSelectionEnd), it returns an array of four numbers, which represents a range of selected cells. And like I've said in the post it will be `[4,1,4,12]` for a human-readable `B5:B13` range of cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of your example, but if you let the colHeaders and rowHeaders to their default values (and setting them to true), you can do that easily in your *afterSelectionEnd* event.

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4tLrvwe/1/) that print **in console** the coordinate of the selected cell(s)

*Getting the column name to construct your range string by using the headers* :

```
hot.addHook('afterSelectionEnd', function(row1, col1, row2, col2) {
  var
  row1Header=hot.getRowHeader(row1),
  col1Header=hot.getColHeader(col1),
  row2Header=hot.getRowHeader(row2),
  col2Header=hot.getColHeader(col2),

  range=row1Header+col1Header+":"+row2Header+col2Header;
  console.log(range);
});
```

After double checking there isn't any function that give you directly your expected result (range), but if you're interested in a more generic one (regardless the headers are present or not, above is just an example) you can let me know and I will try.

Comment: Yeah, I've asked exactly about the out-of-the-box method:) If there's no such method, I can do it manually. Nevertheless, thanks a lot!:)